# How To Calculate Total Time In SQL When Column Is Less Than 0

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-timestamp

I have a table in SQL that looks like the screenshot below and I am trying to calculate the total number of hours or days that the StockLevel column is less than or equal to 0.

[image]

I tried to subtract the time when the item is <= 0 from the time when it is greater than 0, then `SUM` up all the hours, but I have not been able to.

I want to be able to add the total hours in a month that an item was less than 0 maybe by subtracting the timestamps.

```
DATE_DIFF((CURRENT_DATE), MAX(DATE(ledger.EventTimeStamp)), DAY) AS Days_OutOfStock,
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your sample data has no examples of the stock level being less than `0`, so it is not very good sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LAG function to find the stock level for every period:

```
SELECT ItemID, StockLevel, EventTimeStamp AS lo,
       LEAD(EventTimeStamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY itemId ORDER BY EventTimeStamp) AS hi
```

That should give you:

```
ItemID StockLevel lo               hi
536    205        2019-11-05 10:01 null
536    206        2019-11-05 09:37 2019-11-05 10:01
```

You can then use that output to find the negative stock levels and the amount of time

```
SELECT ItemId, DATEDIFF(HOUR,hi,lo) AS p
  FROM (
        SELECT ItemID, StockLevel, EventTimeStamp AS lo,
          LEAD(EventTimeStamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY itemId ORDER BY EventTimeStamp) AS hi
  )
 WHERE StockLevel < 0
```

You should be able to SUM the hours by month, by ItemID

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed(`LEAD`). I appreciate the response.